# ABEL HDL Counter 4bit

Tags: hdl

I want to create counte 4bit generate this sequence : 1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2,0,1... in ABEL HDL. For odd number i make , but for even number fail. Can anyone exlpain me , where is my mistake. 
I think to make like in vhdl.

```
contor=1;
if contor >9 contor = contor + 2; else contor = 8;
if contor >0 contor -2 ;
```

But i don't understand how to use @if . 
This is the code which i made :

```
*<MODULE CounterV2

declarations
"pin declaration  
 X = .x.;
 x = .X.;
"pin of clock , load "
clock  pin 1;  
ld     pin 7;  
i_d    pin 8; 

"output pin"
q3, q2, q1, q0 pin 19, 18, 17, 16 istype 'reg';

contor    = [q3,q2,q1,q0];

        MOD  = [ld, i_d]; 
STOP  =(MOD == [0,  X]); 
PAR   =(MOD == [0,  1]); 
IMPAR =(MOD == [0,  0]);

equations

[q3,q2,q1,q0].clk = clock;
"there is the core of code :D "    
when IMPAR then contor :=1#(contor + 2);
when PAR then {
            contor := 8;
            when contor == 8 then contor :=contor -2;
            }
" there a made test vector 
test_vectors 'test'

([i_d,clock]->[q3,q2,q1,q0])

[0,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[0,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[0,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[0,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[0,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[1,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[1,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[1,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[1,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[1,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];
[1,.c.]->[x,x,x,x];

END 

>*
```

Comment: For those needing an A [ABEL-HDL Reference Manual](http://www.latticesemi.com/~/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/1D/ABEL-HDLReferenceManual.PDF?document_id=589).

Comment: I read Reference Manual. What i don't understand how to usee @if.

Comment: Perhaps you can formulate a specific question and modify your question?

Comment: I think to make like in vhdl. 
contor=1;
if contor >9 contor = contor + 2; else contor = 8;
if contor >0 contor=contor -2 ; 
but in ABEL whrn i make with @if , don't work

Comment: Comments are the place to elaborate your question. There are limitations on possible solutions that may depend on knowing the target device. @if is a conditional directive for including a block of text. How you are trying to apply it isn't apparent from your comment(s).